# Restructure and store data from mqtt broker in the on_message function

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am a beginner, working on an IoT application and I am getting the following continuous stream of data from an mqtt broker that I subscribed as a message topic. I give for reference, what is in each position.

```
IDA/IDB/type/timestamp/valueoftype

 A1/B1/a/1575033906/4
 A1/B1/b/1575033906/5
 A1/B1/c/1575033906/3
 A1/B2/a/1575033906/5
 A2/B3/a/1575033906/6
 A1/B2/b/1575033906/7
 A1/B2/c/1575033906/85
 A2/B3/b/1575033906/6
 A2/B3/c/1575033906/4
 .
 .
 .
```

I want to create a dataframe where I am able to structure each of these combinations of IDA and IDB in order to be able to keep all of their data in a single row and later be able to export it to a csv file. For example like this:

```
data = {'IDA': [], 'IDB': [], 'timestamp': [], 'value of a': [], 'value of b': [], 'value of c': []}
```

If I know all the combinations of IDA and IDB, I thought of splitting the data in the on_message function. Then I thought of using a counter that goes up to three and check that for each pair of IDA and IDB, I find and store all three values in a tuple. Then I could append this tuple in the pd dataframe. The problem here is that the data I get for each pair is asynchronous. For example, check lines 4 and 5 in the above example. The information for A1/B2 is interrupted by A2/B3 for one line until I get the values of A1/B2 again.

Another question I have is, how can I do this when I don't know the types of devices before-hand? For example, down the road I might get a stream of A3/B1 or A4/B3 etc... that I never saw before.

Is there an efficient way to do something like I ask using python and the paho module?

Comment: is the text - IDA/IDB/type/timestamp/valueoftype the name of the topic or the value of the topic ?